# Data Security for PDF Generation

Tags: jspdf

Does jsPdf internally sends the data to any other server for PDF generation? We have sensitive data be exported to PDF formats. So we need to ensure data security

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF is a client side library for generating PDFs. Had tried their example at https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and it does not invoke any server calls.